# How do you calculate P(E1, E2 | H) when E1 and E2 are not independent?

Tags: bayesian, multivariate-analysis

I understand from Bayes Rule that

P(H | E1, E2) = P(E1, E2 | H) * P(H) / P(E1, E2)

When E1 and E2 are independent,

P(E1, E2 | H) = P(E1 | H) * P(E2 | H)

How can I calucate P(E1, E2 | H) when E1 and E2 are not independent?

Answer (score 1):

Either of the following will give you the desired result:

$$\mathbb{P}(E_1,E_2|H) = \mathbb{P}(E_1|H) \cdot \mathbb{P}(E_2|H,E_1) =\mathbb{P}(E_2|H) \cdot \mathbb{P}(E_1|H,E_2).$$